# Synaptics touch pad + three button tap

Tags: 11.04, touchpad, multi-touch

In Windows 7 when I tap my touch pad three times my browser navigates backwards.

Can this fucntionality be replicated in Ubuntu 11?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used it myself but perhaps EasyStroke might be able to recognize that gesture. To install Easystroke on Ubuntu 11.04, open the Terminal and issue these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:easystroke/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install easystroke
```

To add mouse gestures, run this command from the Terminal:

```
easystroke -g
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Doesn't seem to work with Synaptics mousepad - cant get the gesture to record

Comment: hmm wait a sec, had the wrong button selected in preference tab, was set to button 2, set it to button 1

Comment: Sweet, that works, cheers Gus!